# Access VBA Output PDF for each name in multi select list box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to output a report to PDF for each name in a ListBox. Each report PDF must be labeled with the name from the list.

Currently, the code will create the first PDF and name it correctly. After that, the next report doesn't load and the PDF file name becomes *Name1Name2*.

UPDATE: EmployeeNameList is my Multi Select list box built in a form. I'm not getting any errors, but I'm it's not indexing through my selected names. For example, if Smith, John and Jones, Adam are selected this is what happens. A PDF is generated with title "Smith, John 2017 Target Statement" and the next report generated is "Smith, JohnJones, Adam 2017 Target Statement". Apologize for the confusing question.

I'd like Smith, John and Jones, Adam to be separate PDFs.

SOLVED: Debugged and made the following change.

```
strWhere = "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "'" & ","
```

Thanks!

```
Private Sub CreateTargetPDF_Click()

   Dim strWhere As String
   Dim ctl As Control
   Dim varItem As Variant
   Dim ReportName As String
   Dim counter As Byte

   StartingFolder = BrowseForFolder("\\Documents")

   'confirm selection
   If Me.EmployeeNameList.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Must select at least 1 Employee"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'add selected values to string
   Set ctl = Me.EmployeeNameList
   For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected

      strWhere = strWhere & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "'" & ","
      'trim trailing comma and '
      strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1)
      ReportName = Replace(strWhere, "'", "")

      'Select report based on Comp Title
      Role = CompTitleList.Value
      ReportFormat = "Rpt_Target" & Role

      'open report
      DoCmd.OpenReport ReportFormat, acViewPreview, , "[Emp_FullName] IN(" & strWhere & ")"

      'print report
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportFormat, acFormatPDF, StartingFolder & "/" & ReportName & " - 2017 " & Role & " Target Statement" & ".pdf", False

      'Close Report
      DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportFormat

   Next varItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify the other report names, *Name1Name2*. Are you saying no "2017" and "Target Statement" is concatenated? Also, do you want to filter the report to only the listbox names or filter on all listbox names for equivalent reports that are differently named?

Comment: Also, I asked a second question. Do you want to output same exact report content but with different file names? Or do you want to output a report filtered to each selected employee (i.e., different report per employee)?

Comment: Rather than a problem with Access reports (or PDF output), the problem is with debugging the code and tracing through the loop.  You need to place breakpoints, do step-by-step debugging and trace through the code while it is executing.  Then you will observe that some of the code should not be in the loop, because it is repeatedly generating the PDF each time a name is added to the strWhere variable.

Comment: I'm looking to create a different report per each employee. So if 10 people are selected in the list, I would create 10 separate reports. Thanks I'll try debugging, should've done that first!